# Is there such a thing as a fair die?

Tags: dice

Is there such a thing as a fair die? On dice where the number is represented by a scooped out dot, surely that makes a difference? Has anyone done any research?

In fact thinking about it, why would a coin flip be fair? the physics on each side is completely different.

Comment: With respect to fair dice, yes, casinos have a huge monetary interest in having dice be very very close to fair.  The randomization comes in large part from bouncing off the floor and walls of the area where you throw them, and I suspect the dots play an insignificant role in that.

Comment: For the coin, see Andrew Gelman & Deborah Nolan's article in *The American Statistician*, [You Can Load a Die, But You Can’t Bias a Coin](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/diceRev2.pdf).

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5982/is-a-coin-toss-fair

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the concept of 'fair' is hard to define. Since a given roll of the die will produce a deterministic result (in other words, physics determines what the result is) we can't really say that there is a certain 'probability' of rolling a one. This relates to the [mind projection fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_projection_fallacy), which essentially says that probability is a property of one's state of information of a phenomena, not a property of the phenomena itself. Relating to the roll of a dice, the result is not just based upon the die, but also the method in which it is rolled. If we 'know' enough about a given roll (the die's material composition, it's initial orientation, the forces applied to it, the environment it will land in, etc.) we can (theoretically) model all of the motion that occurs in that roll with arbitrary accuracy and instead of finding a 1/6 'probability' of landing on a given side, we will be near certain that it will land on some side.

This all is very unrealistic of course, but my point is that the method of rolling is as important as the die's physical makeup. I think a good definition of a 'fair' die would be one in which under reasonable constraints (on computing power, time, accuracy of measurements) it is not possible to predict the result of a roll with some level of confidence. The specifics of these constraints would be dependent on the reasons you are checking if the die is fair or not.

Aside:
Suppose I tell you I have an 'unfair coin' and I will give you a million dollars if you can correctly guess what side it will land on. Do you choose heads or tails?

Comment: The first paragraph of this answer displays an almost prototypical Laplacian view of randomness.

Comment: This reminds me of the [Eudaemonic Pie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eudaemonic_Pie), where some students tried to predict Roulette based on a shoe-computer :-)

Comment: @cardinal I disagree very much. This is basically the exact view espoused by E.T. Jaynes in his 2003 book, which is a decidedly un-Laplacian view in favor of a much more objective Bayesian view.

Comment: @EMS: **P.S. Laplace** (1814), *Essai philosophique sur les probabilités*, Courcier, **pp. 2-3**: *Nous devons donc envisager l'état présent de l'univers, comme l'effet de son état antérieur, et comme la cause de celui qui va suivre. Une intelligence qui pour un instant donné, connaîtrait toutes les forces dont la nature est animeé, et la situation respective des êtres qui la composent, si d'ailleurs elle était assez vaste pour soumettre ces données  à l'analyse, embrasserait dans la même formule, les mouvemens des plus grands corps de l'univers et ceux du plus leger atome:* ...

Comment: *rien ne serait incertain pour elle, et l'avenir comme le passé, serait présent à ses yeux. L'esprit humain offre dans la perfection qu'il a su donner à l'astronomie, une faible esquisse de cette intelligence. Ses découvertes en mécanique et en géométrie, jointes à celle de la pesanteur universelle, l'ont mis à portée de comprendre dans les mêmes expressions analytiques, les états passés et futurs du système du monde. En appliquant la même méthode à quelques autres objets de ses connaissances,* ...

Comment: ... *il est parvenu à ramener à des lois générales, les phénomènes observés, et à prévoir ceux que des circonstances données doivent faire éclore. Tous ses efforts dans la recherche de la vérité, tendent à le rapprocher sans cesse de l'intelligence que nous venons de concevoir, mais dont il restera toujours infiniment éloigné. Cette tendance propre à l'espèce humaine, est ce qui la rend supérieure aux animaux; et ses progrès en ce genre, distinguent les nations et les siècles, et fondent leur véritable gloire.*

Comment: That is nothing but an argument for determinism. I fail to see what it has to do with probability. Nowhere does Laplace advocate that probability should be understood as the ignorance in one's mind, for example Laplace's *Théorie analytique des probabilités* begins with "The Probability for an event is the ratio of the number of cases favorable to it, to the number of all cases possible when nothing leads us to expect that any one of these cases should occur more than any other, which renders them, for us, equally probable."

Comment: You could certainly argue that the belief that one could, in principle, give a deterministic account of a coin flip or die roll stems from Laplace's view of science. But this is very different than claiming that Laplace understood the mind projection fallacy and advocated for correctly understanding probability as description of a state of ignorance. In Jaynes 2003, he discusses this pretty thoroughly, [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Bayesian-Epistemology-Luc-Bovens/dp/0199270406) has a decent discussion of this idea developing in probability as well.

Comment: @EMS: I think you have interpreted not only that paragraph, but, perhaps, the question itself quite differently from others. You appear to have focused on one sentence regarding the mind-projection fallacy; one which seems a bit out of place. I have focused on the entirety of the rest of that paragraph which, to me, is quite clearly making a statement about determinism and its relationship with our conceptualization of randomness.

Comment: All the rest of the paragraph is about determinism, which is *not* related to interpretations of probability. There are many folks who believe in determinism (even superdeterminism) and yet believe that frequentist accounts still describe probability. This answer highlights that what matters is *what you know* about the die, your subjective degrees of belief about propositions relating to the die. Thinking that *the die itself* has a property, such as $die.randomness$, is the mistake that the MPF is all about.

Answer (score 1):

A little Googling reveals a [Wikipedia (gasp!) article on dice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice). It includes remarks on the precision of dice that mentions the problem of scooping out the dots (they are refilled with material of the same density). Are these going to be *exactly* fair? How will you define that? How close to 1/6 does each result have to be to qualify?

Comment: No die is fair, but to test out whether any given one is biased is a matter of the number of rolls (i.e., time). If during a realistic lifespan of a die and, say, a million rolls, you don't have enough power to detect differences from 1/6, as well as independence of the outcomes, then for all practical reasons it is a fair die. This is the same question as to how many replications one should use in Monte Carlo to detect a small sample bias of an asymptotic estimator: you KNOW there is a bias, but you may fail to find it with 1000 or 10000 Monte Carlo samples, so you conclude it's OK.

Comment: @StasK OK, that's certainly reasonable, and you can get an idea of how far from fair the die is likely to be. But how far is that? No die will be *exactly* fair. 
In this question, the statistics seems relatively straightforward, but the definitions are a little tricky.

Comment: I am thinking in terms of Pearson $\chi^2$ of $H_0: p_1 = \ldots p_6 = 1/6$. What significance level should be attached to this test may be open to discussion. So how the "distance" from fair is $z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{1/6\cdot5/6\cdot1/n}$ where $n$ is the number of times you rolled the die.

Comment: @StasK this seems like a classic [misuse of p-values](http://www.dgps.de/fachgruppen/methoden/mpr-online/issue16/art1/haller.pdf). The probability of observing a given sequence of rolls under the assumption of the die being fair is *not* the same thing as the probability that the die is fair given the observation of a particular sequence of rolls. I think only the latter matters for this question. Your test would only tell you that you cannot reject fairness. It says nothing at all about any prior beliefs on fairness.

Comment: For example, what if I wrote down a maximum entropy list of die rolls, or a list with a large value for some useful proxy of Kolmogorov complexity (such as gzip compression, which is actually used as a proxy in DNA settings). If you did not include the knowledge that this list had been contrived and hand-written a priori, it would seem statistically random to whatever significance level you want. But it's literally not random at all because it was manually chosen, and then say a magnet inside the die was used to force that sequence of rolls to show up.

Comment: I know this is contrived; my point is just that frequentist statistics are totally useless for epistemic questions like this. What you're really asking for is a posterior probability of fairness conditioned on what you know before hand and what you observe. Merely looking for the probability of what you observe given fairness doesn't tell you anything. There are many very easy, highly likely alternatives that could produce the same test statistics for randomness and yet be 100% deterministic.

Comment: I am failing to see the point, indeed. Pearson $\chi^2$ is not a test of independence, and there is a multitude of ways to break it. In Pearson testing paradigm, the choice of the critical level reflects how much trust you put into the null (or how strong the evidence in favor of the alternative should be to reject the null). I am not inclined to go into philosophical discussions though. In Bayesian paradigm, you would have to construct a weird nonregular prior with point mass at the fair point and some absolutely continuous distribution elsewhere, and I just don't know how well it works.

Comment: I'm not sure why you bring up independence; none of my criticisms deal with that. I'm saying that you're working with $P(Data | H_{0})$ when what matters epistemically is $P(H_{0} | Data)$. In the Pearson setting, you also have to assume a weird non-regular prior, and in fact it would be more buried in assumptions and less accessible than setting it up in a Bayesian paradigm, since you're implicitly embedding all of that into the term $P(Data | H_{0})$ by virtue of what that is equal to under Bayes' theorem.

Comment: And in the Bayesian case, you could also concern yourself with some test statistic if you wanted, and set your prior up on the event that the test statistic deviates from some value representing fairness. It's just that instead of testing that with classical tests, you would test it with posterior predictive testing. There are common Bayesian analogues of things like Pearson critical levels in posterior predictive checking.

Comment: I don't think the question is about *either* $P(H_0|Data)$ or $P(Data|H_0)$ it's about how close to 1/6 each outcome has to be for the die to be called "fair".

Comment: I disagree @PeterFlom, look at Danial Johnson's answer above. It's about your own mind's state of ignorance about the die, not about anything empirical regarding the die. This is why $P(Fair | Data)$ and your prior beliefs about the die *do* matter, but the more frequentist approach of basing it on test statistics with $P(Data | Fair)$ *doesn't* matter. It's absolutely not about mere tolerances, because one can always concoct a totally unfair die that satisfies any computable test statistic to within whatever accuracy you want. You really *must* use the idea of priors and states of knowledge.

Comment: [This post](http://lesswrong.com/lw/oj/probability_is_in_the_mind/) might be useful for helping to clarify the misstep in reasoning here.